# RegisterEventSource returns 997 I/O PENDING

Tags: delphi, event-log

What can i do with the error: 997 (io pending) when invoking: RegisterEventSource?

Thanks for help!

```
procedure TForm1.Button111Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StringToAdd: String;
  hEventLog: THandle;
  p: PChar;
  EventID: Word;
  CategoryID: Word;
  wynik: Boolean;
  errnumber: cardinal;
begin
  hEventLog := RegisterEventSource(nil, PChar('app'));

  errnumber := 0;
  errnumber := GetLastError();  //<==997
  showmessage (IntToStr(errnumber));

  if hEventLog > 0 then
  begin
    p := PChar('Test');
    wynik :=
    ReportEvent(
    hEventLog,
    EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, // Event Type
    22, // Event Category ID
    500, // Event ID
    nil, // User SID (optional)
    1, // Number of strings
    0, // Size of Binary Data
    @p, // String to be merged with Text in Ressource DLL 
    nil // Address of Binary Data
    );
    errnumber := GetLastError(); //<==997
    showmessage (IntToStr(errnumber));

    DeRegisterEventSource(hEventLog);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @TOndrej The code added.

Comment: You should only call `GetLastError` if `RegisterEventSource` returns 0. Is 'app' a valid subkey in the registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't testing whether or not `hEventLog` is `NULL` before calling `GetLastError`. You should only call `GetLastError` if the API call failed, as described in the documentation.

My guess is that `RegisterEventSource` actually succeeds and you are getting the error code from the failure of another API call that happened earlier in the execution of your program.

Comment: Right, you are right thanks. The handle is returned and is > 0 so the function succeeded. By the way do you know if there is an api to delete the source from the user log?

Comment: I would always write the test as `hEventLog<>0` rather than `>0` since the documentation states that it returns 0 if it fails. The negation of `=` is `<>`. I don't know what you mean about deleting the source. I'm not very familiar with event log API. Sounds like you might have another question. Don't forget to accept this answer.